# SQL rolling window unique count

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

Is there an SQL equivalent to this line of code in pandas?

Assuming a is a DataFrame object and the index is a list of times (with hours, minutes, and seconds).

x in this case would just be the other column in the DataFrame besides the index.

```
a.rolling('1h').apply(lambda x: len(np.unique(x))).astype(int)
```

Sample result: (Time formatted in HH:MM:SS)

```
                X
05:20:19        4   <- 1 (only 1 unique number)
05:20:19        5   <- 2 (4 and 5 are unique) * same time as before
05:37:18        7   <- 3 (4, 5 and 7 are unique)
05:45:14        4   <- 3 (4, 5, and 7)
05:56:04        4   <- 3 (4, 5, and 7)
06:18:48        6   <- 4 (now 4, 5, 6, and 7)
06:48:34        3   <- 3 (only checks past hour, so now 3, 4, 6)
07:52:48        1   <- 1 (only time in past hour, so only 1)
```

I'm just using vanilla SQL for this as well.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just did! Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT TIME '05:20:19' t, 4 x UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:37:18', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:45:14', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:56:04', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '06:18:48', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '06:48:34', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '07:52:48', 1 
)
SELECT
  t, x, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM UNNEST(arr) y) uniques
FROM (
  SELECT t, x,
    ARRAY_AGG(x) 
      OVER(ORDER BY TIME_DIFF(t, TIME '00:00:00', SECOND) 
      RANGE BETWEEN 3600 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
)
-- ORDER BY t
```

with result as

```
Row t           x   uniques  
1   05:20:19    4   1    
2   05:37:18    7   2    
3   05:45:14    4   2    
4   05:56:04    4   2    
5   06:18:48    5   3    
6   06:48:34    3   3    
7   07:52:48    1   1
```

it uses exact dummy data from your question - I feel in reality you don't have TIME but rather TIMESTAMP  so instead of `ORDER BY TIME_DIFF(t, TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)` you might want to use something like `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t, TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00', SECOND)`  so your query will be like below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 05:20:19' t, 4 x UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 05:37:18', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 05:45:14', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 05:56:04', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 06:18:48', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 06:48:34', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-01-05 07:52:48', 1 
)
SELECT
  t, x, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM UNNEST(arr) y) uniques
FROM (
  SELECT t, x,
    ARRAY_AGG(x) 
      OVER(ORDER BY TIMESTAMP_DIFF(t, TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00', SECOND) 
      RANGE BETWEEN 3600 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
)
-- ORDER BY t
```

with result as

```
Row t                           x   uniques  
1   2018-01-05 05:20:19.000 UTC 4   1    
2   2018-01-05 05:37:18.000 UTC 7   2    
3   2018-01-05 05:45:14.000 UTC 4   2    
4   2018-01-05 05:56:04.000 UTC 4   2    
5   2018-01-05 06:18:48.000 UTC 5   3    
6   2018-01-05 06:48:34.000 UTC 3   3    
7   2018-01-05 07:52:48.000 UTC 1   1
```

> Update - Below is "trick" to address your extra new requirement

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT TIME '05:20:19' t, 4 x UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:20:19', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:37:18', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:45:14', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:56:04', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '06:18:48', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '06:48:34', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '07:52:48', 1   
)
SELECT
  t, x, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM UNNEST(arr) y) uniques
FROM (
  SELECT t, x,
    ARRAY_AGG(x) 
      OVER(ORDER BY TIME_DIFF(t, TIME '00:00:00', MILLISECOND) + 1000 * RAND() 
      RANGE BETWEEN 3600000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
)
-- ORDER BY t
```

with result as

```
Row t           x   uniques  
1   05:20:19    5   1    
2   05:20:19    4   2    
3   05:37:18    7   3    
4   05:45:14    4   3    
5   05:56:04    4   3    
6   06:18:48    6   4    
7   06:48:34    3   3    
8   07:52:48    1   1
```

> One more update :o)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT TIME '05:20:19' t, 4 x UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:20:19', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:37:18', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:45:14', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '05:56:04', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '06:18:48', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '06:48:34', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIME '07:52:48', 1   
)
SELECT
  t, x, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT y) FROM UNNEST(arr) y) uniques
FROM (
  SELECT t, x,
    ARRAY_AGG(x) 
      OVER(ORDER BY ms 
      RANGE BETWEEN 3600000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) arr
  FROM (
    SELECT t, x, TIME_DIFF(t, TIME '00:00:00', MILLISECOND) + 1000 * RAND() ms
    FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
  )
)
-- ORDER BY t
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I tested it out and noticed that, for times of the same value, it displays the overall unique count rather than an incremented amount by row. I've updated my sample result with what I was thinking. I'm really sorry for not including that case earlier. Is this a simple fix?

Comment: Nope. it is not fixable! Unless you will introduce some logic that will be used to determine that first row in your example should be counted as a first and second as a second. Right now they are in the exact same time point '05:20:19' so from `rolling window` logic point of view they both contribute to each other distinct count. For example if you would have milliseconds in your timestamp and they would be different for those two rows  - this would do a "trick"

Comment: ... meantime, there is always workaround  - see update/add in the answer. hope it is self-explanatory  (I am just adding fake random milliseconds) - hope this can work for you :o) . If you have some another field tat you can use as a hint for proper ordering of rows with the same exact time  - you can use it instead of that "fake random" milliseconds value

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! I tested out the new one but I'm getting the error saying that I've exceeded allotted resources due to the OVER(ORDER BY) call. I'm already writing to another table and allowing large data so it seems that the OVER(ORDER BY) is using excessive memory. My dataset is quite big (2+ GB) so that may be why

Comment: this makes sense. to answer your initial question  - i less worried about optimization and put logic for calculating milliseconds inside OVER(ORDER BY). See one more update that hopefully will address memory issue. At the same time, it is known issue when user uses ORDER BY without any partitioning.  So, if you still will have issue  - you should think of partitioning somehow your data.  Meantime, consider at least voting up the answer  - if it somehow helped you!!

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself, using the time range relationship as the joining condition. Here's the MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT t1.time, t1.x, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.x)
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t2.time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AND t1.time
GROUP BY t1.time, t1.x
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b3f06/8)

Comment: Thank you! The query does mostly work except that it doesn't increment the count line in my example result. The result of this query would return "3" for the first 5 rows in my example result when it should increment by row. I'm wondering if it's a simple fix but i can't seem to think of one

Comment: I had the tables in the ON clause backwards. It works now.

Comment: Thank you! I took a look at the demo and it does seem to work. The one case I want to mention (and I'm really sorry for not including it earlier) is when there are times of the same value. If they are of the same value, the code you provided doesn't increment the count for the rows with same time value but rather provides the overall unique count. I've updated my sample result with the case as well. Is this a simple fix?

Comment: When the times are the same, why should they get different counts? And how does it decide which one gets the lower count? Is there an ID column that orders them? Or should they be ordered by X?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can use a sub-query, see below:

```
SELECT t1.date
,      (SELECT count(DISTINCT t2.x) FROM mytable AS t2
           WHERE  t2.date <= t1.date
           AND    t2.date > DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)    
       ) AS uniq_rolling_count_of_x 
FROM mytable AS t1
ORDER BY 1
;
```

Comment: Thank you! The query does mostly work except that google bigquery doesn't allow nested selected statements (sorry for not clarifying earlier) and also it doesn't increment the count line in my example result. The result of this query would return "3" for the first 5 rows in my example result when it should increment by row. I'm wondering if it's a simple fix but i can't seem to think of one

Comment: You need to use standard SQL in BigQuery to use a subselect in the SELECT list.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I tried standard sql and I get this error though: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join